# Prove the following is a homomorphism and describe its kernel.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove the following is a homomorphism and describe its
>   kernel.

**The function $f:  \mathbb{RxR} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ given by $f(x,y)=x+y$**

I just want someone to confirm my answer:

My answer:

Since $\mathbb{RxR}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are both groups and there exists a function $f$, then for any two elements $x$ and $y$:

$$f(x,y)=x+y=f(x)+f(y)$$

As for kernel, would it be $K=\{(-x,-y) \in G |  f(-x,-y)=0\}$

Comment: this can't possibly be correct. How do you go from $x+y$ to $f(x)+f(y)$? what is $f(x)$ or $f(y)$ for that matter???? (answer: nothing, as it is undefined). Look closely at the domain for $f$. What is the group operation on the domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(assuming additive notation throughout)

To show that $f$ is a homomorphism, you need to show $f(z_1 + z_2) = f(z_1) + f(z_2)$ for all $z_1$ and $z_2$ in the group $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.  Since the structure on this group is coordinatewise addition, the statement to be proved is of the form $f(x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2) = f(x_1,y_1)+f(x_2,y_2)$.

For the kernel, you should aim for a more intuitive description.  The definition is 'those $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) = 0$'  The definition of $f$ should make it clear that this can be further simplified.

Comment: Alright! Let's see if I get it this time: $f(x,y)=f(x_1,y_1)+f(x_2,y_2)=f(x_1+x_2)+f(y_1+y_2)=(x_1+x_2)+(y_1+y_2)=f(x)+f(y)$

Comment: Would I have to state what $x_1$ and $x_2$ or is that understandable? Also, i'm not quite understanding what you are trying to say for the kernel part. Do you mean that the kernel is (0,0)?

Comment: I am having trouble parsing your argument.  Since $f$ is a binary function, I don't know what $f(x_1+x_2)$ or $f(x)$ could be, for instance.  Are $x$ or $y$ ordered pairs or single real numbers?

Comment: I guess I'm being being deliberately cryptic about the kernel part, you shouldn't take my words as indicating any particular answer.

Comment: f(x,y)=f(x1,y1)+f(x2,y2)=f(x1+x2)+f(y1+y2)=(x1+x2)+(y1+y2)=f(x)+f(y‌​)

Comment: @RolfHoyer, the OP is confusing binary with unary functions.  Writing $f(z_1)$ is only going to add to this problem.

Comment: I'm confused.  Why are you taking $n$ pairs now?  What does the pair $(x,y)$ have to do with the pairs $(x_i, y_i)$?  The right hand side of your argument is plugging a single real number into $f$, which is invalid.

Comment: OK, maybe things are more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Homomorphism: 
$$f((x,y)+(x',y'))=f((x+x',y+y'))=x+x'+y+y'=(x+y)+(x'+y')=\\=f((x,y))+f((x',y'))$$

Kernel: $$0=f((x,y))=x+y$$
This holds exactly when $y=-x$, i.e. $Ker(f)=\{(x,-x):x\in \mathbb{R}\}$